# Queried Users Showing Same and Wrong Registration Date

Tags: wordpress, date, foreach

I am trying to display user registration date in a loop of queried users, unfortunately, it's displaying same date of wordpress installation for all queried users. I have searched for solutions online all to no avail. Here is my code:

```
      <ul>
            <?php

            $users = array_unique(get_objects_in_term( array(104, 106), 'profession' ));

             foreach ( $users as $user_id ) {                  
            ?>
                <li>
                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email', $user_id ), '400' ); ?>
                    <div class="project-overlay">
                        <a class="preview" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $user_id ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>

                        <h3 class="boxeq3"><?php
                        $userNm = the_author_meta( 'display_name', $user_id );
                        echo $userNm; ?> </h3>
                        <p>
                        <?php 
                        $registered = date_i18n( "M m, Y", strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user_ID ) ) );
                        echo 'Member since: ' . $registered;
                         ?>                       
                        </p>                           

                    </div>
                </li>

                <!-- End Loop -->

                    <?php }  ?>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Is the same date has the year 1970 ?

Comment: By the way what do you get when you echo  get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user_ID )

Comment: @tousif It shows same date which is wordpress installation date